# At what point does an API return ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_LOADED?

Tags: c, debugging, winapi, x86

I'm trying to move an application (that I did not write) from Windows 7 to Windows 10. But it fails to start on Windows 10 with this "helpful" error message:

[image]

I isolated a spot where the error takes place:

[image]

So what I'm getting is that `LoadAccelerators` returns `NULL` and `GetLastError` is set to `15105` or `ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_LOADED`.

Does anyone know what does that error code mean?

PS. The `hInstance` parameter for `LoadAccelerators` is set to the correct instance of the module that this API is called from (i.e. `0x6F0000` in that screenshot.)

Answer (score 1):

OK. I think I got it.

What was missing is a Multi-User Interface `.mui` file with the resources. ([Here's more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee845043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).) For Windows components these are located in `C:\Windows\System32\<lang>\<ImageName>.mui` folder for `64-bit` apps, or in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\<lang>\<ImageName>.mui` for 32-bit apps.

So copy it from there and place it into `<lang>\<ImageName>.mui` folder in the destination where the app has to run, and it will fix that error.